# How to find the position of a letter in a word with similar characters using IndexOf()

Tags: c#

This is a part of the code I used in my "Hangman" game;

```
namespace Hangman_Game
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            selectWord();
        }

```
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("madurangasac@gmail.com\n+94712913837\nAll Rights Reserved*");
    }
    // METHODS **********************************************************************
    //stringArray---------------------------------
    string[] animals = new string[]{"cat","rat","bat","cup","dog","bag","pen"};
    string word;
    int x;
    int y;
    int correct = 0;
    int wrong = 0;


    //select word --------------------------------
    private void selectWord()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        x = rnd.Next(7);
        word = animals[x];

    }

    private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectWord();
        textBox2.Text = "***";

    }
    // play-------------------------------------------
    private void play(string key)
    {
        if (word.Contains(key))
        {
            int position = word.IndexOf(key);
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Remove(position,1);
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Insert(position, key);

        }
        else
        {
             y = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            y--;
            textBox1.Text = y.ToString();

        }
        if (word == textBox2.Text)
        {
            correct++;
            MessageBox.Show("*** CORRECT !!! *** \nYou have won "+correct.ToString()+ " times.");
            selectWord();
            textBox2.Text = "***";
            textBox1.Text = "20";
        }
        else if (word != textBox2.Text && textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            wrong++;
            MessageBox.Show(" YOU LOST :( <><><> You have lost "+wrong+" times.\n let's START again !!!");
            textBox1.Text = "20";
            selectWord();
            textBox2.Text = "***";
        }



    }
    // keys -----------------------------------------------

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("q");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("w");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("e");
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("r");
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("t");
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("y");
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("u");
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("i");
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("o");
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("p");
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("a");
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("s");
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("d");
    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("f");
    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("g"); 
    }

    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("h");
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("j");
    }

    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("k");
    }

    private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("l");
    }

    private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("z");
    }

    private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("x");
    }

    private void button23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("c");
    }

    private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("v");
    }

    private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("b");
    }

    private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("n");
    }

    private void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        play("m");
    }


}
```

}

But When I used a word with similar letters as the "word", the IndexOf() method only
identifies the position of first letter,  of the similar letters.

How to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide an input of what you have (the words) and what you expect as an output? Thanks

Comment: what should be the output if you use word `word`?

Comment: You have not even mentioned which "word" you are searching or what `key` is. Show a sample which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: First thing you should think about is how to get rid of all those button event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
String.IndexOf(string value, int startIndex)
```

to get the index of occurrences after the first.  It starts searching from startIndex so you can ignore matches you've already hit.

MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an example using the IndexOf with the startindex parameter to replace all the occurrence of * with the guessed letter

```
string secretWord = "TestMeTestMe";
textBox2.Text = new String('*', secretWord.Length);
int position = -1;
char key = 'e';
while((position = secretWord.IndexOf(key, position + 1)) != -1)
{
    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Remove(position,1);
    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Insert(position, key.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the found indexes.

```
var word = "ThisIsYourWord";
var key = "o";
List<int> indexList = new List<int>();
while (word.Contains(key))
    {
        indexList.Add(word.IndexOf(key));
        word.Remove(indexList.Last(), 1);
    }
return indexList;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, try

```
        string wordToSearch = "HereIsTheWord";
        string characterToFind = "e";
        int currentIndex = 0;
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

        while(currentIndex >= 0)
        {
            currentIndex = wordToSearch.IndexOf(characterToFind, currentIndex + 1);

            if (currentIndex >= 0)
            {
                indexes.Add(currentIndex);
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < indexes.Count; index += 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(indexes[index]);
        }
```